# Timer is working with delay when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift3, timer, xcode8

I have created timer and it is working fine when app is in foreground and active. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reinstateBackgroundTask), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

}
    func createTimer (){
        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(self.runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(gameTimer, forMode: .commonModes)
        registerBackgroundTask()

    }

    func registerBackgroundTask() {
        backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
            self?.endBackgroundTask()
        }
        assert(backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    }

    func endBackgroundTask() {
        print("Background task ended.")
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }
```

But my timer is working with delay when app is in background. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Any suggestions. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you set the flag in plist

Comment: Yes. I set the flag in plist also.

Comment: background app refresh in settings is on ?

Comment: @サンディープ Yes. It is on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506398/nstimer-is-not-fired-in-time